# How to make a UITextField Inherit from two classes?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, cocoapods, multiple-inheritance

Some of my UITextFields are inherited from KaedeTextField from [TextFieldEffects](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects)

I want to make these textfields to have masks from another framework, the [AKMaskField](https://github.com/artemkrachulov/AKMaskField)

How could that be done? How can I make a textfield have the style of the KaedeTextField but at the same time also have the masks from AKMaskField?

is it possible to do that in Swift using protocols and extensions?

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer is, not without taking the time to take both libraries apart and understand how they work and then merge there functionality back together into a single class. Swift/ObjC does not support multiple inheritance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift **does not** support multiple inheritance for classes. Additionally you could conform to a protocol, but since they are both subclasses of the `UITextField`, there is no reasonable way and frankly - it doesn't make any sense, since they both handle it their own way.

You would *(most likely)* end up with a subclass of the first library and then you could recreate a missing feature from the second one.